# How to obtain an ID token From Python App Engine User Object

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-oauth

Using Google's OAuth2, I could get an id_token using something like this: [Google ID Token Client](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/flexible/endpoints/clients/google-id-token-client.py#L40)

Up until now, I've been using App Engine's built in user object for all my auth needs and haven't even needed to use any of the Oauth library inside of my code. I don't see an equivalent method of getting an id_token in the GAE user object docs.

Is there a way to either get the same id_token from my GAE user object directly or to create an "Oauth2 compatible object" directly from the GAE user object?

Comment: I don't think you can.  I switched from GAE users to Oauth2 and I had to have all users login again to convert their accounts.